# jqGrid get row element within formatter

Tags: jqgrid

I created a custom formatter for column in jqGrid. Is it possible to modify the parent TR of that cell? As I can see, the formatter executed before the TR with data added to the DOM so it seems like i can't get the row element by rowID.
I want to change style / CssClass of the TR based on rowObject that I receive in formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at `rowattr` callback (it is available since jqGrid 4.3.2) which allows to modify the row attributes during rendering. The more detailed description is available in following pull request:

- [Implementation of rowattr callback](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/284)

Comment: Hhhh, where you have been yesterday? It could save me about 4 hours :)) Anyway thank you, I implemented it again using rowattr.

Comment: @AlexDn I'm sorry to say that I was sleeping :D