# Customization of Jqgrid UI by row basis

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**Hello experts**

I am using jQuery grid in my web application and it is very great to use. Now i have a special requirement for it.

> can i customize its display like i want some rows text has strike ?
>   through on it based on some condition and others display as it is.
>   please see the attached picture for more clarification.

For example ,

I have a three rows in one grid.
grid has a **isRemoved** hidden column , which has value of true or false. 
now if this column has value true then whole row of the grid has strike through on it means all the text of the row has strike through on it. if this column has value false then it is displayed normally ( without strike through).

**how can i achieve this ??**

```
Thank You
Mihir Parekh
```

Comment: give me couple of minutes, your demo is almost ready on jsfiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid get row element within formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059895/jqgrid-get-row-element-within-formatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/piyushsardana/yN4kM/8/

Check this fiddle . Now here i have Client colName(colModal:name) as hidden column and i have two rows. One has value test and other has test1. Now I'm getting my row data in loadComplete and based on the value I'm applying css class to that row.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is a lot better to use `rowattr` callback for that purposes, I have linked a question with informations about it as a possible duplicate.

Comment: i think you give me a solution , i will try it now and come here back. thanks Piyush